# How to convert JavaScript object to a normal string?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I want to post a variable through AJAX.

The `typeof` variable is `"object"`.

If I directly post an object, the AJAX fails. I used `JSON.stringify` but then it’s in `["10","11","12"]` format.

I need a string similar to `10,11,12`. How do I do that?

Comment: What is your variable? What does this object contain? If it is an array and you want to convert it to comma-separated string, use `Array.prototype.join`. If it is an object, then is it keys or values or what? Show some code.

Comment: Do you have some code that you have written. If yes then post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String()` function converts the value of an object to a string. The `String()` function returns the same value as `toString()` of the individual objects.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x1 = ["10","11","12"];
    var res = String(x1) + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to convert object to string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call method join on your array like this :

```
console.log(["10","11","12"].join(",")); // 10,11,12
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was an array so toString() should do it.
but  ["10","11","12"] was the correct representation of the javascript object.
[] tells it was an array, that information is permanently lost when you generate something like 10,11,12